# Is there any Logviewer application available to see 4GL logs? -PROGRESS 4GL

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

For me its quite hard to view the 4GL log file. Is there any log viewer application available?

Comment: What exactly are you finding "quite hard"?

Comment: [Why shouldn't I assume I know who downvoted my post?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/388686)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logfiles are plain text, any text viewer will do.

Which is best depends on your OS and personal preferences.

On linux I'd use `less`, or `vi` for "small" logfiles.

On windows I use `baretail` regularly, but I also use Vs Code, Editpad, ..., notepad

Answer (score 0):

The 4GL Log files should really not be that hard to read?

As a possible built in option: in OpenEdge Management there's a log viewer.

On a newly set up server with classic appserver/adminserver it generally runs on `http://<server-ip>:9090/` with credentials admin/admin (to be changed at first login).

This might be different with PAS (I'm not working with that, at least not yet).

Answer (score 0):

We have our databases hosted in AWS so I send all my logs (DB, Webspeed, PASOE, AdminServer, etc etc etc) to Cloudwatch with a relevant retention policy. It's not hard to build a Date/Time parsing formula to calculate when the log entry happens. That way I can give people access to the logfiles easily without them needing access to all the different servers. It's a very neat solution. And we can send non-Progress logs over too, so Apache etc. And grepping them is dead easy too.